# Need help figuring out how to implement UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-menu

Essentially I'm asking what techniques to use in Eclipse/Android Studio to make a UI that looks like the FaceBook UI withtabs on the bottom and their typical action bar on the top with content in the middle.

I've been kind of dealing with this issue for quite some time now and as I have a project deadline coming up figured it was finally time to get stackoverflow's opinion. What would be the best way of creating a social media app that models FaceBook's user interface. By this I am referring to something with the four tabs on bottom and search/back and profile buttons at the top, with some sort of fragment changing in the middle.

The solutions I have currently tried are using a split actionbar by forcing the top into a custom layout and the bottom into an options menu; however, this resulted in giving the options menu the drop down option instead of tabs (if there's a quick fix for this like setting a custom layout to it please lmk because this is my current setup).

For the main content view I originally tried using fragments and then switching between fragments by using functions and buttons inside the fragment class to switch views; however, this required childfragment manager, and for some reason that never worked properly, so instead I ended up switching activities instead of fragments which was horribly slow.

If you guys have any suggestions on how to do this properly please please either tell me how I would go about this, or better yet please show me some very good examples on how to do these things.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you show us the image of UI? Then it will be more clear, rather than reading 3-4 paragraphs.

Comment: I really wish I could, but for copying issues I can't post the actual UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use any proto typing tools to create UI . Some tools include Proto.io , Fluid ui etc

Comment: That's actually some amazing stuff and I will probably use it to get my graphics down; hoever, what I'm asking for is how would I go about creating those UI's on android studio/eclipse my bad I should've been more specific in my question I edited it now though